# The "no-ansi" option does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to create laravel project on windows but this problem show to me and
I try update the composer.
the php version is 8.0.6,
the composer version is 2.0.14,
the laravel version is 4.2.5,

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/installer/issues/182

Comment: Please share more details. If this is an issue with the installer itself, you should put it to their bug tracker. Otherwise please share what you've tried to resolve the problem

Comment: I have the same problem:
I installed laravel from scratch with composer create-project laravel / laravel projectName.
everything worked fine with that first project.
But then when I wanted to create a new project with: laravel new projectName,  I got the same error.

Comment: @sclero And what have you tried to resolve the problem? There's even a bug report about this behaviour, the link has been posted here

Comment: i've used the solution of @miken32 and it's worked!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of `laravel new your-project-name` you should use `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 4.2.*`

Comment: i had the same problem and this didn't work

Comment: Okay, sorry, I didn't know that. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: thank you this work for me, but I don't detect the version of laravel I use : 
`composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name`

Comment: But I bet, in that case the version defaults to the latest one, which currently is 8.x

Comment: I guess this is good if you want a 7 year old version of Laravel... ‍♂️

Answer (score 11):

Per comments on this [Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/installer/issues/182#issuecomment-851654779) this is a problem with the latest version of the Symfony Console component, which is 5.3.0. Composer is based on this library, but you can downgrade to the previous version 5.2.8 with this command:

```sh
composer global require symfony/console:5.2.x
```

And then force the update with:

```sh
composer global update
```